# Apache2 conditional: If local image not found, look in stage server?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a stage and dev server. I periodically pull the database from stage to local, but not the images due to lack of write permissions on stage. I know that you can write rewrite conditions for pulling all images from a remote location, but is there any way to tell Apache to first look on local, and if not found, then grab the images from remote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-f` flag in a `RewriteCond` statement to make a rewriterule conditional on whether or not the file exists locally...and then use a proxy or redirect rule to actually make the image available.  This does it using a proxy rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /images/(.*\.(png|jpg)) http://dev/images/$1 [P]
```

This is not actually a tested configuration, but should hopefully point you in the right direction.  The [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) has a detailed description of `RewriteCond` an `RewriteRule`, and a Google search for something like [rewritecond file exists](http://www.google.com/search?q=rewritecond+file+exists) will get you useful results.